Difference between a comparison of independent variables t.test and linear regression model of one category?
The thing is I am trying to obtain confidence intervals of several variables (food, blood chemical analysis...) of patients who are divided in two groups according the intervention. Until now I was obtaining the pvalues, but we're moving towards confidence intervals
Here lies the mathematical doubt, that maybe it's pretty basic, but I totally oversaw.
The thing I was doing until now was
#being dat the database
# variable1 is quantitative, continuous and normal distributed
# category has 2 categorys, but for some analysis will be 3
pvalue <- car::Anova(lm(variable1 ~ category), dat), type=2)$`Pr(>F)`[1]

#pval < 0.05
[1] 0.02088357

#moving towards confidence intervals 

model <- lm(variable1 ~ category), dat)
CI1 <- sprintf("%.2f",confint(model)[2,])

sprintf("%.2f",confint(lm(model))[2,])
[1] "3.94"  "46.76"


But I thought I could easily do the same applying  t.test of independent samples, thinking that t.test of independent samples = anova of 1 factor similar or equeal to lm of one predictor category
#being dat the database
J<-t.test(subset(dat, category== "0") [["variable"]], subset(dat, category== "1")[["d_carnicos_v01"]], paired =F)

J$conf.int
[1] -46.768318  -3.933538
p-value = 0.02091


I more or less understand that regression tends to quantify how one variable changes with the predictor variable. But I thought being a category would be like an Anova
So:

Why is statistical significance varies using the regression model or t.test? I guess I simplified some step which is not that obvious (for me)
The ANOVA of the model is showing a pvalue of 0.02 while the interval doesn't contain the zero. I don't really get the gist of the question there, doing the ANOVA of the model is something inherited (that I didn't question, wrong) but I thought it was correct and similar to get the conf.int of the covariate or factor of interest


The values are virtually identical, both the p-value and the confidence limits. The default in t.test uses the Welch-test which doesn't assume equal variance. The regression assumes homoscedasticity. Try setting var.equal = TRUE in t.test and compare again.

You're right. Exactly like that. But I have never used the homoscedasticity in the t.test. In fact, it's something I was taught to check when conducting ANOVA but in practice I don't see statisticians around me doing it. Should be a mandatory procedure?

If you're using a t-test, the best practice is to use Welch's test by default, without even checking homoscedasticity (with a Levene's test or something like that). See this paper for example.
